# Two spinners's text should start exactly under each other in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I want two spinner's text to start exactly under each other. In the XML-file I put the spinners exactly under each other but when content is displayed the texts do not start at the same horizontal positions. How can I do that? Further, the textSize can't be changed (I tried different values for the attribute textSize but this did not have any effect.

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="265dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/commentButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="comment_Button"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.87"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/comment" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/comment"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8" />





    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ordering_button"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:text="@string/order_Button"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#121212"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.885" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorGreen"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="29sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:fontFamily="casual"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.41" />




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/size"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.481" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.642" /><![CDATA[

    />


    ]]>


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup_Size"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.485"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.862"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">




        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_Button_Small"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
            android:text="@string/small"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.322"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_Button_Medium"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/Medium"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.962"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_Button_Large"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
            android:text="@string/Large"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.962"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </RadioGroup>





    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.59"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.645"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:popupBackground="#5fe0f5"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.59"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.723"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:popupBackground="#5fe0f5"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.72" />





</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'd appreciate every comment as I tried a lot without success (with paddings and alignments).

Here is a picture of the current and the desired layout for the 2 spinners[image]. Both texts should start at the same horizontal position and also the arrows should be exactly underneath each other.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of what you want to achieve and what exactly is current state?

Comment: Thanks user8608556 for your comment. I updated the question and included what you asked me for. Do you have an idea, how I can archieve that? I'd appreciate any further comment from you.

Comment: Why dont u make your spinners match_patent (0 dp in constraint layout) ?

Comment: Thanks Pouya for your answer. I now did that (see answer below). But why do I have to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your desired screenshot & your layout. Check below code with comment marked **//user8608556** for your easy understanding.

1. Making width of spinner to 0dp to constraint in layout
2. You should align spinner2 w.r.t spinner1.
3. So adding required margin on spinner1 at start & end for spacing, spinner2 will adjust according to it as per pt#2 (you can adjust margin as per your need).

[image: Spinner closed]
[image: Spinner open]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="265dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


<!--    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/comment"-->
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/commentButton"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="comment_Button"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.87" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="comment"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8" />


<!--    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"-->
<!--    android:text="@string/order_Button"-->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ordering_button"
    android:layout_width="163dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"

    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#121212"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.885" />


<!--    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"-->
<!--    android:background="@color/colorGreen"-->
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="29sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:fontFamily="casual"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.41" />


<!--    android:text="@string/size"-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewS"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.481" />

<!--    android:text="TextViewB"-->
<TextView

    android:id="@+id/textViewB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.642" /><![CDATA[

/>


]]>


<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup_Size"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.862"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.485">


    <!--        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"-->
    <!--        android:text="@string/small"-->
    <!--        android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"-->
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/r_Button_Small"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.322"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <!--        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"-->
    <!--        android:text="@string/Medium"-->
    <!--        android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"-->
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/r_Button_Medium"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:checked="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.962"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!--        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"-->
    <!--        android:text="@string/Large"-->
    <!--        android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"-->
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/r_Button_Large"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.962"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</RadioGroup>


<!--    android:background="@color/md_teal_800"
android:entries="@array/days_of_week" -->
<!-- //user8608556   Both spinner1 & 2 layout_width make 0dp to set in constraint added marginStart & end, change as per need -->
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:popupBackground="#5fe0f5"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.59"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.645" />

<!--    android:background="@color/md_teal_800"
android:entries="@array/days_of_week_options"-->
<!-- //user8608556   //spinner2 start & end align to spinner1 so just margin on spinner1 will do the trick-->
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:popupBackground="#5fe0f5"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/spinner1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.59"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/spinner1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.723" />

<!--    android:text="TextViewC"-->
<TextView

    android:id="@+id/textViewC"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.72" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I suggest to [check this link as to understand how constraint layout work](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html). Just to answer in short -> "0dp" is the equivalent of "match_parent" in ConstraintLayout.
Its upto you how to constraint your views inside parent. They can be constraint to parent or another view as per your need. Considering you wanted to align both spinner to each other, setting constraint of one to another I don't have to repeat it moreover it is more flexible if you want to support different screen sizes.

To change text size(/style attribute) of spinner [Refer this](https://www.broculos.net/2013/09/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-color.html) . In short, Spinner doesn't expose internal textView hence setting textSize doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot user8608556 for your answer. It basically works. However I do not really understand what you have done. How did you know that you have to spinner2 start & end align to spinner1? Why do you choose 0dp for width and not match parents or wrap content. Further how did you know that you have to use the attributes "constraintEnd_toEndOf" and e.g. not "layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf". Normally in constrained layout I allign everything to the parents because then you can just drag and drop the item (for the spinner this did not work)

Comment: There is still the problem that the textSize attribute does not affect the real text size at all. How come?

Comment: @VanessaF I have edited answer to add more insight. Hope this helps:) Consider going through constraintlayout document to understand more.

Comment: Thanks user8608556 for your help. I accepted your answer. For me it is really strange that changing the textSize in a Spinner can only be done with such an effort. Why did the not just simply have an XML tag attribute for that as in a textView?

Comment: Regarding the ConstraintLayout: I have already watched a lot of tutorials but the way they use the ConstraintLayout is quite complicated and not easy to understand. This is why I use another approach: I just put the 4 constraints for each element to the parents. This way, I can simply drag and drop the elements in the layout and in almost of all cases I have experienced so far the layout in the app looks as the desired one. Unfortunately for the spinners this was not the case and I had to use your approach

Comment: I suggest you to try codelab for the same, it might help to get better hang of it. Regarding [spinner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner) its adapterView hence you don't have direct access to its textView.

Comment: Thanks user8608556 for your help and great effort. I have already read the google documentation about the constraintLayout and I think it is easier if you just align everything to the parents and drag and drop the elements in the view. Thus you avoid the complex inner rules of the constraintLayout and as said before, in most of my fragments and activities it works perfectly (I use this approach for over 20 fragments). Just really rarely (e.g. Spinner or ScrollView) the approach does not work perfectly. But in generall I think it is better to use my approach because it is way easier

Comment: Regarding the textSize of the Spinner: Can you think about an easy way of changing the textSize? Maybe this can be done programmatically in the Java code and not in the XML code?

Comment: You can align spinner2 to parents [check code created here](https://gist.github.com/prasad-333/e8d2c94c93a5f48baa5c2b534ace8b09). Its just some sort of code maintainability if you know both are aligned to each other so in future just changing alignment on one will do. Constraining on parent won't going work for all cases especially if you are going to use barrier, guidelines, helpers etc. There is reason google provided with different constraint options(took good years to get stable version of it), _If you want to learn to swim, jump into the water_ thats gonna help in long run:).

Comment: For textSize you can possibly change using styling but need to figure out proper parent styles etc, i don't suggest that as it might get changed on some custom android OS version or in future version, just to avoid breaking your code.

Comment: Thanks 333 for your comment. But  the ConstraintLayout is unfortunately quite complex for beginners. It is extremely difficult to figure out to decide which attribute (layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf, layout_constraintStart_toStartOf etc.) to use. And then you also have to determine the destination for all constraints and for every item. That makes it quite complex. So my approach is the more natural one for designing as you can just drag and drop the items in the layout editor

Comment: When using the constrainedLayout you have to spent much time in deciding about the constraints. And then you have to check it all the time in the emulator because the layout in the layout editor looks different to the real one. When you just align everything to the parents the layout looks equal in most cases. Thus you don't have to use the emulator that often. I read and watched lot of tutorials about the constrainedLayout and I just think that for most cases it is not benefical except if you just align everything to the parents and design in a natural way. It's not worth the effort imho.

Comment: do you know why when using always constraints to the parents and drag and dropping items sometimes it does not work? In most cases it is not a problem but for example when using Spinners or ScrollView it does not work.

Comment: Hey 333. Thanks for your help and effort. I really appreciate it. Do you have any comment regarding my last comments about the ConstraintLayout? I'd really appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: Hey Vanessa, sorry for the late response. As I mentioned earlier to you couple of times, ConstraintLayout are build for a reason but if you are more comfortable with your natural way I just can't help suggesting something against a built framework by Google's expert. To help you I even created code & shared with you both ways of doing it. It will be better if you post your queries on created [gist](https://gist.github.com/prasad-333/e8d2c94c93a5f48baa5c2b534ace8b09) as this thread getting unnecessarily stretch & we should respect SO community guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort 333. I really appreciate it. Unfortunately I do not use Github and I was just asking you if you know why in most cases my natural approach of using constraintLayout works but sometimes it does not and if you know a good source to learn the ConstraintLayout (because the offical developer page of Googel is horrible imho). But it is okay if you do not want/can answer my questions. You have already done a great job and I am quite thankful.